# Display a component in a grid pattern. Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a card component that I would like to show in rows and columns, I haven't been able to figure it out, I would want to do it without using any dependencies if possible. I want a simple grid like 4 or 5 per row and adding a new row when necessary.

These components are to display the categories created by the user, the amount will change because on this page is where the user can create more, update them or delete the categories.

Right now I'm displaying them simply like this but they're all just one on top of the other

```
<div v-for="(category, index) in categories" :key="index">
    <category_component :category="category" v-on:delete="confirmDelete" v-on:edit="editItem"/>
</div>
```

Is there a simple way to display them a certain number per row dynamically?

Edit: 
I added some flex parameters as suggested like this

```
<div class="category-container">
    <div v-for="(category, index) in categories" :key="index">
        <category_component :category="category"
            v-on:delete="confirmDelete" v-on:edit="editItem"/>
    </div>
</div>

.category-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Now it is displaying in rows but is there a way to limit the amount per row? It's displaying 6 but they are really pushed together and then the row below they are far apart. Ignore the new button.

[image]

Comment: Why not using `display:flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` (Basic Grid)?

Comment: If you want, you can set `flex-basis: 25%` inside the parent component `<style>` to display 4 items per row. Consider using CSS Grid for more control

Comment: @Lyokolux where would I put that?

Comment: It depends on your definition of *"simple"*. But considering the number of devices, browsers and the variety of contents each column might hold, the true answer is: there's no simple answer. Responsive grid is the most common reason behind people using frameworks. `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap` on the parent is a good start, but has to be followed through by width control on children.

Comment: @tao where am I supposed to add the flex stuff to the `div` where the `v-for` is?

Comment: The `v-for` div are the children. You need to apply display flex and flex-wrap to their parent.

Comment: @tao I added more info to the question, take a look

Comment: You have to read the flexbox guide. If you want them more generous, set a `min-` and `max-width` in percent on children, or add some padding to them. And also add `justify-content: flex-start` if you want them to stack left on last row. Flexbox is not "simple", although once you get the hang of it, it's not that complex, either. But it does allow you to have full control on alignment, distribution and flow of content. To separate them, add some margin...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212017/discussion-between-tao-and-nancy).